# How to use regex_replace to replace a substring with another in a string and in the same time keeping the whole text intact?

Tags: c++

I have a line full of words with many spaces between them. I heard that by using regex_replace I wont modify the spaces only the string words and replace them with another string of my own.

---

So I have a string vector of words on the third line with size mentioned on the second line, and also a string who contains a whole line of words on the first line. 
The words in the vector that I can find in the line I want to replace with the number of "*" as their size.
I have to solve this in C++.
Example:

```
input:
ana arepere    mere si surcele
3
are si cele
output: 
ana ***pere    mere ** sur****
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are right. With `std::regex_replace` this can be easily achieved. You need to run a loop over all to-be-replaced-strings in the `std::vector`. Then you build a new replacement string with the number of stars, depending on the size of the to-be-replaced-strings.

`std::string` has a constructor for that purpose. You can handover the number of characters that should be in the new string and of course what character.

That is basically all. Please see:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // The string with any data in it
    std::string source{ "ana arepere    mere si surcele" };

    // The substrings that shoub be replaced
    std::vector<std::string> toBeReplaced{"are","si","cele"};

    // Loop throug the toBeReplaced strings
    for (const std::string& tbr : toBeReplaced) {

        // Build the replacement string
        std::string replacement(tbr.size(), '*');

        // Replace
        source = std::regex_replace(source, std::regex(tbr), replacement);
    }
    // Show result
    std::cout << source << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I was on the right track tho, all I didnt know was that I should've converted the tbr to the regex type.